# Спарсить картинки с яндекса ( PHP + simple html dom parser)

Tags: php

Нужно:
Спарсить первую картинку с сервиса https://yandex.kz/images при помощи PHP и библиотеки simple html dom parser.

Вот мой код. Дальше продвинуться не могу. В чем проблема? В какую сторону копать, чтобы дописать парсер?

```
require_once('simple_html_dom.php'); // файл с настройками

$key = "скачать антивирус malwarebytes";
$key = urlencode($key); <br>
$key = str_replace("+","%20",$key);<br>

$link = "https://yandex.kz/images/search/?text=" . $key;

    $ch   = curl_init($link);   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,
TRUE);  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE); //следовать за
редиректом  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE);
//отключить проверку ССЛ    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER,
FALSE); //отключить проверку
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_USERAGENT,"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1;
Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.88
Safari/537.36"); //установить юзер агент <br>   $html = curl_exec($ch);<br>
    curl_close($ch);<br>    $html = str_get_html($html); <br>   echo $html;
```

Comment: что у вас там за `<br>` посреди кода, и в чем собственно проблема-то мы догадаться должны по вашему?

Comment: br - это при оформлении топика  поставил. его в коде нет.

Comment: дак вы что здесь хотите узнать-то? как испоьзовать simple html dom ? дак это в документации написано. И вообще, загрузка картинок в поиске явно аяксом происходит, так что вы вообще зря взяли этот инструмент.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

перед закрытием тега PHP "?>" добавьте следующее

```
foreach($html->find('img[class=serp-item__thumb justifier__thumb]') as $element)  {
    echo $ready_img = $element->src . "<br>";
    //echo $ready_img = $element->src . "<br>";
    }
```

Все УРЛЫ картинок. Выбирайте любую.

Comment: комментарий дублируется. Я его удалил.